# Why is smartmontools advising me to upgrade Seagate ST31000528AS firmware version CC34 to CC49?

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade, firmware

I have a Seagate Barracuda 7200.12 model ST31000528AS.

[`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org) warns me when querying the drive that a firmware update might be available and instructs me to a seagate website [link](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/213891en) where however there is no changelog shown.

Searching the seagate.com website I could not find any advisories for my current firmware version CC34.

Searching the [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org) mailing lists shows no reason for displaying the warning apart from the fact of update being available on Seagate website.

Searching the Seagate forums leads to a lot of cases where performance worsens and a link to a HP-branded update of a previous firmware version that fixes slow performance on very low temperatures.

Given the above, does anyone know what changes have happened inbetween CC34 to CC49? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Seagate publishes the changes the differences between the two revisions one can only assume the only changes were because of compability updates to support new devices released after the HDD you have was released.

Its very unlikely the exact changes have been released by Seagate.  Unless there is a specific problem you are trying to solve, skip the update, you risk data loss by updating the firmware on a HDD.

Comment: I'm not referring to risks of not following the procedure, but to the risks of staying at CC34

Comment: @CostinGușă - Your question was not clear.  You asked what are the risks of upgrading the firmware, and I supplied those risks, the main risk is data loss.  Besides knowing there is a newer firmware what are the reasons you want to upgrade?  If there isn't a specific problem you are trying to solve then why bother?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Smartmontools is suggesting you update the firmware is almost certainly because it has detected that a more recent versions exists. These tools typically don't have any way of knowing if the newer version will actually benefit you, they just alert you to the fact that they exist.

You were right to try to find out if the newer firmware had any benefits for you. As you have drawn a blank there, you face the usual two choices

1. Don't update if you are not aware of any problem (if it ain't broke, don't fix it). It is always possible that the update will **cause** a problem.
2. Update so that you always have the latest (hopefully best) version. It is theoretically possible that the update solves a problem that you didn't know you had.

Which of those you choose is up to you.